Make header sections in a div the same height
I have 3 columns where i want the divs to be the same height, i also would like to have the header sections inside those divs to be the same height no matter the content inside of it. I am not sure if this is possible with css only but have high hopes that it is.
Here is my codepen of what i am working on: https://codepen.io/theller5567/pen/bGPmyjy


.promo-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  font-family: "Work Sans 1", sans-serif;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
       column-gap: 20px;
  row-gap: 20px;
}
.promo-wrapper .promo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 12px;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.promo-wrapper .promo-header {
  background-color: #002168;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.promo-wrapper .promo-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
.promo-wrapper .promo-content ul li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.promo-wrapper .promo-btn {
  background-color: #b2c200;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
<div class="promo-wrapper">
  <div class="promo">
    <div class="promo-header">
      <h2>OMNI Tissue Homogenizer (TH) plus a 5-pack of NEW 12mm Omni Tips for an unbeatable price of $799!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-content">
      <img src="https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=300&amp;height=223&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png" width="300" height="223" loading="lazy" alt="th-12mm-sale" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%; width: 300px;" srcset="https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=150&amp;height=112&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 150w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=300&amp;height=223&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 300w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=450&amp;height=335&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 450w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=600&amp;height=446&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 600w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=750&amp;height=558&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 750w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=900&amp;height=669&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 900w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
      <br>
      <h3>Why This Offer is Insane</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Regular Price for OMNI Tissue Homogenizer (TH): $1,095</li>
        <li>Regular Price for 5-pack of 12 mm Omni Tips: $100</li>
        <li>Total Regular Price: $1,195<br><strong style="font-size: 16px; color: #222222;">Your Price Today: $799 – A Massive Savings of $396!</strong></li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      
    </div>
    <div class="cta-button">
      <a class="promo-btn" href="/contact-us">Contact us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="promo">
    <div class="promo-header">
      <h2>Free Sample Pack - Get Precision and Convenience with Our New Omni Tip™ 12mm Disposable Probes</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-content">
      <img src="https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png?width=250&amp;height=263&amp;name=OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png" width="250" height="263" loading="lazy" alt="OMNI - 12mm tips Hybrid" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%; width: 250px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;" srcset="https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png?width=125&amp;height=132&amp;name=OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png 125w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png?width=250&amp;height=263&amp;name=OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png 250w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png?width=375&amp;height=395&amp;name=OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png 375w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png?width=500&amp;height=526&amp;name=OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png 500w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png?width=625&amp;height=658&amp;name=OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png 625w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png?width=750&amp;height=789&amp;name=OMNI%20-%2012mm%20tips%20Hybrid.png 750w" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 100vw, 250px">
      <br>
      <p>Our new 12mm disposable tip probes are designed to support the <span style="color: #0033a0;"><a href="https://www.americanlaboratory.com/914-Application-Notes/35175-A-New-Homogenizing-Technology-Designed-to-Save-Time-Improve-Yield-and-Eliminate-Cross-Contamination/" rel="noopener" target="_blank" style="color: #0033a0;">rigorous demands of processing samples.</a></span></p>
<br>
<p>The 12mm Omni Tip patented design significantly reduces the hassle of disassembly and maintenance of traditional stainless-steel generator probes</p>
      
    </div>
    <div class="cta-button">
      <a class="promo-btn" href="/contact-us">Contact us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="promo">
    <div class="promo-header">
      <h2>Get 50 FREE Pre-filled Tubes</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-content">
      <img src="https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=300&amp;height=223&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png" width="300" height="223" loading="lazy" alt="th-12mm-sale" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%; width: 300px;" srcset="https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=150&amp;height=112&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 150w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=300&amp;height=223&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 300w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=450&amp;height=335&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 450w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=600&amp;height=446&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 600w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=750&amp;height=558&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 750w, https://omni-inc.com/hs-fs/hubfs/th-12mm-sale.png?width=900&amp;height=669&amp;name=th-12mm-sale.png 900w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
      <br>
      <h3>Why This Offer is Insane</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Regular Price for OMNI Tissue Homogenizer (TH): $1,095</li>
        <li>Regular Price for 5-pack of 12 mm Omni Tips: $100</li>
        <li>Total Regular Price: $1,195<br><strong style="font-size: 16px; color: #222222;">Your Price Today: $799 – A Massive Savings of $396!</strong></li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      
    </div>
    <div class="cta-button">
      <a class="promo-btn" href="/contact-us">Contact us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Based on the picture i am wanting the blue sections to all be the same height. You can see the last column the blue header is not the same height as the others.


I was able to make the header sections have an equal height by adding @supports (display: contents) {
.promo {
display: contents;
}
} but then my box-shadow goes away because the container div is essentially ignored. I need to have the box shadow effect.
